# Git porcelain option not showing anything?

Tags: git, command-line-interface

I'm trying to parse the output from the command `git status --porcelain`.
As stated in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18075356/414385).

The problem is that I'm not getting any output when testing this in the cli:

```
git status

output:
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

And with `--porcelain`

```
git status --porcelain

output:
(nothing :)
```

Can someone please explain what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git status --porcelain` only shows status of files in a machine readable format. - Check the exit code in order to make sure no error occurred (!= 0 indicates an error).

As "nothing to commit, working directory clean" is shown by `git status` you get an empty list of files. - Change some files or stage some changes and you'll see some output.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no untracked files and no changed file `git status --porcelain` shouldn't output anything, try to add a file `touch new.file` or change an existing one an try again.